# Connect to Elasticsearch Service from Lambda in the same VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

How can I access an Elasticsearch Service instance from a Lambda function without applying an IAM role?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to configure two Security Groups:

- Configure the Lambda function to use the VPC.
- Create a Lambda Security Group (`Lambda-SG`) and configure the Lambda function to use it.
- Create an ElasticSearch Security Group (`ES-SG`) and configure ElasticSearch to use it.
- In `ES-SG`, add a rule to permit inbound connections from `Lambda-SG` on port 9300 (or whatever port your ES is using).

That is, `ES-SG` should refer to `Lambda-SG` to permit inbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an IAM role for a lambda function and provide the IAM role access to ES.

Comment: How is this meant to assist connectivity between EC2 and ElasticSearch? They do not communicate via IAM.

Comment: I dont see the post mentioning EC2 ? Within the same VPC connectivity already exists between Lambda and ES however Lambda function needs an IAM role with appropriate access to talk to other AWS services. Subnets within a VPC are configured to allow communication by default

Comment: Oops, you're right. It's Lambda instead of EC2. However, IAM is only required for calls to AWS that create/delete the ES cluster. IAM isn't used to login to/use ES.

Comment: I am pretty sure if you don't provide the IAM role, Lambda functions uses, access to ES it won't be able to talk to it.

Answer (score -1):

If your Lambda runs within a VPC, you can configure the ElasticSearch access policy to an IP-based policy.

AWS does provide samples for various kinds of access policies.

[IP based access policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html#es-ac-types-ip)