# AWS Lambda Timeout - Trying to Figure out the Cause

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function return in C# which will process events from Dynamo Table and index the event in ElasticSearch. Here's the thing, I created a public domain and testing it. It just works fine. But later, for security reasons, I configured another ElasticSearch domain inside my VPC like below in Terraform.

```
vpc_options {
    security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.elasticsearch_sg.id}"]
    subnet_ids = ["${data.terraform_remote_state.base_platform.private_subnet_ids}"]
}
```

But now my lambda functions failed with just logging TimeOut Exception. When I rolled back my changes it just work fine again.

So, After reading this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html, I decided to add my lambda function in the same VPC. Still I got a TimeOut Exception.

Looking for some further direction, what might be the cause.

This is something comes to my mind, I might be wrong
After configuring ElasticSearch and Lambda function in same VPC, I would expect this to work. But still this fails. In this case, I'm guessing Dynamo Event is not in the same VPC or Lambda function which is inside the VPC doesn't have access to the public table. I'm very confused. Looking for directions

Comment: Could you share stacktrace? may be timeout configuration value for lambda which is default to 3 seconds

Comment: I Set up my timeout to 100. @ManojRana

Comment: If Elasticsearch is deployed in VPC then you need to deploy the Lambda function into the VPC and allow access from the Lambda's security group to the ES cluster (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955126/if-lambda-can-access-the-elasticsearch-with-in-same-vpc). Sounds like you also need the Lambda to access DynamoDB so the Lambda must either have a route to the internet (requiring an internet gateway and NAT in a public subnet) or you need a VPC endpoint to DynamoDB.

Comment: @jarmod Nice! I tried that in the mean while by enabling VPC Endpoint to DynamoDB. 

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "dynamo_vpc"{
  vpc_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.base_platform.vpc_id}"
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.ca-central-1.dynamodb"
}

But still timed out